# java filter forward throwing illegalstateexception

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters

i m intercepting the request url and forwarding that to another url

like

`some_application/image_20.jpeg` to `some_application/image_345.jpeg`

I am doing this using filters.

now my code is:

```
   public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
                     FilterChain chain)
    throws IOException, ServletException {
    //some code

    RequestDispatcher request_Dispatcher=request.getRequestDispatcher(forward_url);
    request_Dispatcher.forward(request,response);



 Throwable problem = null;
 try {
 chain.doFilter(request, response);
 }

    catch(IllegalStateException ise)
    {

    }
    catch(Throwable t) {

 problem = t;
 t.printStackTrace();
}

  }
}
```

as  i m using `RequestDispatcher` to forward requests.. and its working correctly

is it normal for this code to throw `IllegalStateException`

as i catch it in my code and leave it not to throw any messages..

now i m worried if it can harm the overall container or slow the performance

or i can change some code and not get any `IllegalStateException`

thanks

Comment: Where is the exception thrown? my guess is in the chain.doFilter()? Blind guess: can you really go on filtering after the request has been dispatched (and served)?

Comment: ya in the chain.dofilter as it is only in the try catch block and i can stop the ile using my code... now the filter is working correctly... but still a ile???

Comment: so should i try and remove the line chain.doFilter

Comment: ok right... no use of chain.doFilter.. nice one bert...

Comment: You should never catch `IllegalStateException` since that indicates a problem on the programmer's side. Rather show us the stack trace and make sure the exception never occurs under normal circumstances.

Answer (score 5):

```
request_Dispatcher.forward(request,response);
chain.doFilter(request, response);
```

You cannot do both these things. By the time you pass the request along the chain to the end resource, you have already committed a response via `forward`.

Comment: yup no need of chain.doFilter()